# Windows 8 emulator on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

By building my android aplication on phonegap for windows 8 i got a .xap file. Now **am not having windows 8 pc or windows 8 phone.** I want to test my xap file, so what can i do now? Is that possible to run the xap file on windows 7 if so how ? I tried by installing windows software development kit but i couldnt find any emulator. Is there any other way to run the application on windows 7 desktop ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no emulator for Windows 8 on Windows 7.

Your best bet would be [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). Two most popular options are [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). You can run virtual PC and install Windows 8 on it (you'd need a Windows 8 installation though).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released new virtual images with different Operating Systems and Browsers on [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/virtualization-tools). On the right side of the page you'll find different virtualization options as well as download links to different images. You can download and use these images without having to worry about buying any license, getting the system installed, etc. (they're time limited, but you can just reset your virtual machine at will).